# Disable mysql general query log for specific user (or schema)?

Tags: mysql, logs

MySQL can log all queries in what is called ["General Log"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/query-log.html)

Is there a way to keep this query log but skip all queries for a specific user? Or maybe for a specific database?

---

I would like so because I have a database that one user connects to (application user), so I want to have the query log to make debug easier in staging area, but I also have a daemon that connects to this same database with another user, and daemon issues like 1 query per second. So my query logs are 80% filled by this daemon's query so I would like to skip them to make it easier to find app user's queries.

Comment: The `general_log` server setting's scope is GLOBAL only. You cannot disable it for a separate connection (account) and/or for a separate database.

Comment: See if `pt-query-digest` can help in looking at the file.

Comment: @RickJames AH, neat for those who use Percona. But I don't when developping on local environment (sounds a bit heavy for that). I'm simply viewing the logs with `cat` or `tail` or plain text editor, hence my willing to have mysql not put these query into the file (rather than filter when displaying the file, tho I could do `cat file.log | grep -v 'table_name_or_schema_name'`)